# Chameleon Bootloader: Install Ubuntu Netbook Remix from USB flash drive?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, networking, netbook, bootloader

i have an **Dell Mini v10** and tried to install OS X onto it. Wasn't too happy with the performance and so I want to install **Ubuntu**.
Problem is: I have installed Chameleon Bootloader and when I try to boot from usb with the Ubuntu img (see [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-create-an-ubuntu-installation-usb-on-the-mac/) ).
When I select the USB drive to boot from the screen prompts me:
Operation system not found

I thought that the bootloader might be the problem as Ubuntu relies on GRUB. I cannot boot into OS X anymore as I get a kernel panic.
Anyone has an idea how to install Ubuntu on the netbook? Or how can I install a new bootloader without any bootable option - I cannot get a terminal/shell...

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: does the drive boot on other systems?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to boot off of a Ubuntu LiveCD and create the USB with the built in USB Creater tool. IMO this is had the highest level of success for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want OS X on the system at all,and the problem is due to chameleon  you could probably try wiping the whole disk (with say something like dban) , then installing.

if you have a accessible windows or linux system, i'd also suggest giving unetbootin a shot for making the installation media.

Answer (score -1):

No problem with your pirated OSX, just that you did copy image as a file to the drive and did not use any of 10 ways that offficially work to create a bootable USB.

Comment: Where did you get the "pirated" from ?

Comment: It is written between letters when you type C H A M E L E O N D E L L M I N I 1 0

Problem is with your USB drive where you copied inactive image file as a file, when you needto use DD or any of boot USB maker tools.